# Why RNFS can't write file as a doc file in iOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fs

I'm trying to open a doc file written using RNFS. But I'm unable to open that file. When I try to open the file using the word application in iOS , I'm getting this error showing "Can't open file, file format doesn't match the file extension".

```
 var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/test.doc";
 RNFS.writeFile(
  path,
  "Project Details\n",
  "utf8"
 );
```

But this is working fine in android.

Answer (score 2):

iOS only provides `.doc` files for read only. You have to use `.docx`.

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
var path = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/test.docx"  : RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/test.doc";
```

Comment: I've tried this, but still not working. This will create a file named test.docx but when I try to open it I'm getting this error "Can't open file. Sorry, something went wrong and test.docx can't open"

Comment: No, after creating the file, you can find that file from the files manager in the iPhone.

Comment: Have you checked the size of the file?

Comment: Yes, its only 468 B .

Comment: Does this file not open on your computer, either?

Comment: Yes it does in LibreOffice for mac.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197596/discussion-between-vinay-narayankutty-and-hong-develop).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LibraryDirectoryPath` to Write file in iOS

> const localFile = `${RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`